# Access report prompts for parameter on every page of printing job

Tags: ms-access

I am new to Access.  I just created my first DB w/ a report in Access 2010.  The report requires a parameter to run. If I run the report, then try to print, it prompts for the parameter for every page of the report.  This is a deal breaker for me.  Is there something I can do to "fix" this.  I might expect it once, but not for every page!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using VBA you can use an InputBox to acquire the value from the user on the Report's Open event. Then use that value to create an SQL Statement and set it to the Report's RecordSource. Your code should look something like this. Note that I didn't write the code in MS Access or test it.

```vb
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel as Integer)
    Dim sSQL As String, sInput as String
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM Contacts "
    sInput = InputBox("Enter a Name", "Enter a Name")
    If sInput <> "" Then
        sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE FirstName = '" & Replace(sInput, "'", "''") & "'"
    End If
    Me.RecordSource = sSQL
End Sub
```